# how can I flask fastest? using sqlalchemy in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a question.

I used to python 3.4, sqlalchemy, pymysql

But now my flask is very slowly at web perhaps 150s.

I have a database at MySQL 50000row.

How can I using fastest in flask used to sqlalchemy?

models.py

```
class User(Base):
__tablename__ = 'test'
Location = Column('Location',String(20),index=True)
    Date = Column('Date',String(50), primary_key=True,index=True)
    T1 = Column('T1'Float(precision=5), index=True)
    T2 = Column('T2',Float(precision=5), index=True)
    T3 = Column('T3',Float(precision=5), index=True)
    T4 = Column('T4',Float(precision=5), index=True)
    T5 = Column('T5',Float(precision=5), index=True)

def __init__(self, Location, Date, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5):
   self.Location = Location
   self.Date....
```

main.py

```
@app.route('/test/<Location>', methods=['GET'])
def test(Location):
    data = db_session.query(User).filter(Location=Location)
```

Please can you help me?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? How it is set up? Is it running on your local machine?

Comment: Try running your query directly in a MySQL client and see how long it takes. That should tell you if it's Flask or MySQL.